# Redirect All subdomain url to specific url using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

how to rewrite like

`(anything).example.com/(anything)` to `example.com/(anything)`

for example :

`img1.example.com/test1.jpg` to `example.com/test1.jpg`

`img105.example.com/anotherimage.png` to `example.com/anotherimage.png`

`tdr.example.com/a.css` to `example.com/a.css`

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^(.*)\.example.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  !^www\.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```